# How do I use git to manage a codebase with separate client assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control

I have a project that contains a core Ruby on Rails project that will be deployed for several different clients. I'd like to be able to update the core application while maintaining separate changes in the views and public folders.

In other words I need every time I change app/controllers/product_controllers.rb all the clients get that change while having app/view/products/index.html.erb or public/css/styles.css be managed separately for Acme and Newco and Jones etc.

This seems different than what branches/tags is meant to solve since the changes in those folders would never be merged.

Comment: maybe submodules or bundle the common part of your app as a gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create separate branch for every client and merge changes that need to be merge(in your case controllers) every time when significant change is made and leave alone files specific to given client.

You can also divide your code in modules(I'm not going to suggest how exactly - it's up to you and different for every project) and hold them as different projects.

In unix-like systems, if you have something like "core of the application" (something common to every project) you can even hold it in one folder and use symbolic linking to use is in different projects.

Comment: One of my concerns with a branch per client is how to merge the changes. Imagine that I add a new attribute to the product model and then some kind of processing in the controller for the new attribute and then a new helper that the controller uses. If I do this in Acme's branch, how do I get those back to everyone else efficiently? A separate merge command isn't bad for 4 clients but what about when I have 100 clients? Especially if the above leads to 4 or 5 separate merges.

Comment: If you're going to use same code in so many(maybe even 100) projects then it should be treated as separate module(kind of kernel or something - in ruby maybe gem[I'm not ruby person so I'm not sure]) with its own history of changes, own documentation and own very strict API. Apart from it in such case unit testing is crucial. I can't imagine how are you going to handle so many diverging branches. It's true that 4,5 is ok - not 100. It's not a problem of merge(you can write bash script to do it massively).It's problem that something may break in project #42 and you will not even be aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could still use a branch for each client. Branches don't have to be merged. Or you could fork for each client.  It's different than branching in that it creates a separate repo